# Match shortest substring in list using for loop

Tags: python, string

I am trying to match items (single words) from one list with items (full sentences) from a second list. This is my code:

```
tokens=['Time','Fun','Python']
sentences=['Time is High', "Who's Funny", 'Pythons', 'Python is Nice', "That's Fun!"]

for word in tokens:
     for line in sentences:
         if word in line:
             print(word,line)
```

The problem now is that my code outputs substrings, so when looking for a sentence in which 'Python' occurs, I am also getting 'Pythons'; similarly, I am getting 'Funny' when I only want the sentence containing the word 'Fun'.

I have tried adding spaces surrounding the words in the list, but this is not an ideal solution, because the sentences may contain punctuation, and the code does not return a match.

Desired output:
 - Time, Time is High
 - Fun, That's Fun!
 - Python, Python is nice

Comment: `Fun` and `Fun!` are obviously not the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want exact matches, it'd be better to use `==` instead of `in`.

```
import string

tokens=['Time','Fun','Python']
sentences=['Time is High', "Who's Funny", 'Pythons', 'Python is Nice', "That's Fun!"]

for word in tokens:
     for line in sentences:
         for wrd in line.split():
             if wrd.strip(string.punctuation) == word: #strip method removes any punctuation from both sides of the wrd
                 print(word,line)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not as easy (requires more lines of code) to achieve retrieving "Fun!" for `Fun` and at the same time not "Pythons" for `Python`.. It can be done of course but your rules are not very clear to me at this point. Have a look at this though:

```
tokens = ['Time', 'Fun', 'Python']
sentences = ['Time is High', "Who's Funny", 'Pythons', 'Python is Nice', "That's Fun!"]

print([(word, phrase) for phrase in sentences for word in tokens if word in phrase.split()])
# prints: [('Time', 'Time is High'), ('Python', 'Python is Nice')]
```

---

Below you get exactly the same thing only this time instead of a list comprehension you use good old for loops. I though it might help you understand the code above easier.

```
a = []
for phrase in sentences:
    words_in_phrase = phrase.split()
    for words in tokens:
        if words in words_in_phrase:
            a.append((words, phrase))
print(a)
# prints: [('Time', 'Time is High'), ('Python', 'Python is Nice')]
```

What is happening here is that the code returns the string it found and the phrase in which it found it. The way this is done that it takes the phrases in the `sentence` list and split them on whitespace. So "Pythons" and "Python" are not the same as you wanted but so is "Fun!" and "Fun". This is also case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use dynamically generated regular expressions, ie for "Python" the regexp will look like '\bPython\b'. '\b' is a word boundary.

```
tokens=['Time','Fun','Python']
sentences=['Time is High', "Who's Funny", 'Pythons', 'Python is Nice', "That's Fun!"]

import re
for word in tokens:
    regexp = re.compile('\b' + word + '\b')
    for line in sentences:
        if regexp.match(line):
            print(line)
            print(word,line)
```

Answer (score 0):

tokenized sentence is better then split it by space, since tokenize will separate punctuation.

for example:

```
sentence = 'this is a test.'
>>> 'test' in 'this is a test.'.split(' ')
False
>>> nltk.word_tokenize('this is a test.')
['this', 'is', 'a', 'test','.']
```

Code:

```
tokens=['Time','Fun','Python']
sentences=['Time is High', "Who's Funny", 'Pythons', 'Python is Nice', "That's Fun!"]
import nltk
for sentence in sentences:
    for token in tokens:
         if token in nltk.word_tokenize(sentence):
             print token,sentence
```

Comment: Why does your code work? Consider adding some context to your answer.